# Stubborn zurb modal won't fade away

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am switching between two modals.  The first modal contains a button that calls this function:

```
function teamControl(action) {
    $('#teamControlsModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');

    if (action == "create") {
        $('#teamFlavorText').html("Create a Team");
        loadBusinessInfoSelectBox('businessSize');
        loadBusinessInfoSelectBox('businessType');
        loadBusinessInfoSelectBox('businessLocation');
        $('#createTeamModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }
}
```

Which in turn opens the following modal:

```
<div id="createTeamModal" class="reveal-modal">
<form id="createTeamForm" style="width: 480px; margin: auto;" 
    novalidate="novalidate"></form>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>
```

But, when I click the X to close the second modal, the modal itself goes away but the screen is left grayed out.  No javascript error at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have another modal shown before that modal is shown? What version of Foundation are you using?

Comment: I did have another modal shown previously, and I'm using v4

Comment: The previous modal has a button that onClick is running a function that calls 'reveal,'close' (to close itself) and then 'reveal','open' of the second modal.  I wonder if the onClick function opening the second modal is preventing the first one from closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual solution to this problem:

Edit foundation.reveal.js.  At the end of the close function, insert the following line.

```
this.hide(this.settings.bg);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I did have another modal shown previously

That's a bug in V3 and I have not encountered it in V4 simply because I implemented the same approach when closing my modals in V3. This is what I have for V3:

```
function closeModals() { 
    $(".reveal-modal").trigger("reveal:close"); 
}
```

That ensure I don't have any modals open before I do another one. In V4 I have this:

```
function closeModals() { 
    $('.reveal-modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
}
```

I never encountered that issue ever again.

Comment: I updated the first modal's onclick to call closeModals and then call the function required, but I got the same behavior.

Comment: Care to put it in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure how well it would cram into jsfiddle...  But I'll update the question with the function bridging the two modals.

Answer (score 0):

I had to async this work because the function of the onclick from the first modal was opening the second modal and preventing the first modal from cleanly closing.

```
var openModal;

function teamControl(action) {
    $('#teamControlsModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');

    if (action === "create") {
        $('#teamFlavorText').html("Create a Team");
        loadBusinessInfoSelectBox('businessSize');
        loadBusinessInfoSelectBox('businessType');
        loadBusinessInfoSelectBox('businessLocation');
        //$('#createTeamModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        openModal = 'createTeamModal';
    }
}

function asyncModalOpen() {
    if (openModal !== '') {
        $('#' + openModal).foundation('reveal', 'open');
        openModal = '';
    }
}

function highFreqTimer() {
    asyncModalOpen();
}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("highFreqTimer()", 500);
</script>
```